# Descrepancy in div structure when rendered from different views

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views, markup

I have a confusing HTML situation in the rails application that I'm working on.  So I have a `new` view and an `edit` view that invoke the same partial view `_form.html.erb`.

The _form partial is structured as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for @incorporation do |f| %>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="basic_info" class="form_section">
      Some stuff
    </div>
    <div id="address" class="form_section"> More stuff</div>
    <div id="equity" class="form_section">.....</div>
    <div id="directors" class="form_section">...</div>
    <div id="ip" class="form_section">....</div>
    <div id="contractor" class="form_section">....</div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**The problem is:**  when the pages are rendered in the browser, the `edit` view shows the `div#contractor` outside of `div.panel-body` BUT in the `new` view, it's inside where it's supposed to be.
See the firebug outputs I grabbed below:

**..../new/**
[image: new.html.erb]
**..../edit/**
[image: edit.html.erb]

But again, both `edit` and `new` point to exactly the same `_form.html.erb`

See below:

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Edit</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

The only thing different between them is literally the little heading I put at the top.
My question is whether anyone has any guess as to what might be causing this.
  Clearly I'm not expecting anyone to comb my code for THE bug, as I truncated it to avoid an insanely long post.  But I'd be interested if anyone's encountered this before or has any suggestions for where I might begin looking.

**UPDATE 1:**

It just gets weirder.  So I decided to take the div.panel-body out of the partial and put it into `edit.html.erb` like so:

```
<h1>Incorporation</h1>

<div class="panel-body">

  <%= render 'form' %>

</div>
<br/>

<%= link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

However, the problem remained the same.

**Update 2:**
I've found a workaround by moving div#contractor above div#ip.  It would seem that there's something amiss with div#contractor then.  I've included it below

```
<div id="contractor" class="form_section">
  <div class="form-left"><h2>Employees Contractors</h2></br><p>stuff</p></div>
  <div class="form-right">
    <div>
      <%= company.simple_fields_for :contractor_people do |contractor| %>
        <%= render 'contractor_person_fields', f:contractor %>
      <% end =%>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Person', company, :contractor_people, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form_subsection">
      <div>
        <%= company.simple_fields_for :contractor_orgs do |contractor| %>
          <%= render 'contractor_org_fields', f:contractor %>
        <% end =%>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Company', company, :contractor_orgs, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you actually see it happening when the page is rendered or just inside firebug? One thing that seems odd is `<% end =%>` - if you want to truncate the trailing whitespace, you need to use `-`, not `=` before the percent sign..

Comment: @JiříPospíšil Thanks for the reply and the tip regarding the `-` vs `=`.  I do in fact see it rendering incorrectly in the browser, not just firebug.